# Adding a dynamic link to Microsoft Teams message

Tags: azure-logic-apps, microsoft-teams, power-automate

I'm using Azure logic apps to post a Teams message (using `v3`) to a channel that we have upon a trigger. When I'm trying to add a dynamic link to the content that I'm posting - it fails.

If I use an example message like below, where the `SomeAction` is generating a json result and the `.link` is a URL property:

```
`Example message looks like <a href="body('SomeAction').link]">this</a>`
```

`<` and `>` characters get encoded and I lose the clickability of the text.

Looks like in Microsoft Flow - they have an html icon button which seemingly turns off the encoding - see here: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/Flow-Bot-unable-to-add-clickable-URL-to-Teams/idi-p/277965

so it looks like this: [image: msflow_htmlbutton]

but logic apps don't have the same button. If I try to add link using a static URL with the button that's provided, it works. I can't use Microsoft Flow, because it's functionalities compared to logic-apps seems to be somewhat limited.

I'm wondering if there's any way of posting a dynamic link in Microsoft Teams using logic apps?

Comment: Did you try [SomeText](Dynamically generated URL). This work properly in almost all MS products(Logic Apps and in Flow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured this out.

As I've said before if we just added `<a href="body('SomeAction').link]">` the tags get encoded.

Turns out this encoding happens only when we add text / code through the online editor / textbox.

The trick is to navigate to *Code View* and ensure the encoding is removed through the arm template.

[image]